# Problems with respect by direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

So I'm working through Atiyah and Macdonald as preparation for a Masters project and I've already hit a conceptual bump. They describe a ring direct product, but then prove that for coprime ideals it's equal to their intersection. How can that be the case, since members of the intersection will be individual elements while members of the direct product will be sequences? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If $I$ and $J$ are coprime ideals of $R$ then $IJ=I\cap J$. But here $IJ$ is a product of ideals: the ideal of $R$ generated by elements $ab$ for $a\in I$ and $b\in J$, not a direct product of rings.

Comment: I get that for the two ideal case. But their proof that it follows for a family of ideals invokes the direct product. It's that which I'm struggling with.